# pandas dataframe index by a tuple?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with tuple as index:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"col1": [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)], "col2": [1, 2, 3]})
df2
     col1  col2
0  (1, 2)     1
1  (3, 4)     2
2  (5, 6)     3
df2.set_index("col1", inplace=True)
df2
        col2
col1        
(1, 2)     1
(3, 4)     2
(5, 6)     3
```

But if I do index like `df2.loc[(1,2)]`, it raises any error. Any idea how to enable object tuple as index?

Comment: `df2.loc[[(1,2)]]` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) out of it. Refer to [`pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html)

```py
df2.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df2['col1'].values), inplace=True)

df2.loc[(1,2)]
col1    (1, 2)
col2         1
Name: (1, 2), dtype: object
```

You can drop `col1` if you wish to.